# How to get full response string in AFNetworking from server?

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I'm using AFNetworking 3.0 with `session manager` like this:

```
    sessionManager = AFHTTPSessionManager(baseURL: baseURL)
    sessionManager?.post(url, parameters: parameters, progress: nil,
                         success: {(task: URLSessionDataTask, responseObject: Any) in
                           print(task?.response)
                         , failure: {(task: URLSessionDataTask?, error: Error) in
                         print(task?.response)
    })
```

When I print `task.response` object, I only get the headers. How do I get the full response string and error, if any, from the server?

Comment: use responseObject.response

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
    print(responseObject.response)
    print(responseObject.response.request)  // original URL request
    print(responseObject.response.response) // URL response
    print(responseObject.response.data)     // server data
    print(responseObject.response.result)   // result of response serialization
```

Comment: What type is your `response`? Not quite sure which one you're referring to. The `task?.response` from my question is of type `URLResponse`

Comment: Yes task.response

Comment: let me know if you get desire output

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlresponse None of those attributes are available..

Comment: The link you sent is native url response. AFNetworking have these values. I am using it.